# mvc4 same dbcompiled model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Controller in MVC4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172074/add-controller-in-mvc4-not-working)

I'm using VS 2010 Premium. I have a MVC4 project using SqlCe 4.0 with a entity framework model.

Model is:

```
public class ProjectBuild
{
  public int ProjectBuildID {get;set;}
}
```

When I try to create a new controller with the built in scaffolding too I get the following error:

> "Unable to retrieve metadata for ProjectBuild"."Using the same
>   DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database
>   servers is not supported. Instead, create a separate DbCompiledModel
>   for each type of server being used".

Below is my connection string

Comment: The connection string is missing ...

Comment: this is my connection string:                                       add name="ProjectBuildContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|DB.sdf"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"