# create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning ASP.NET MVC from tutorials of Microsoft :

[http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller)

At the link above mentioned, while adding a controller named `MoviesController` I am getting this error:

"Unable to retreive metadata for 'MvcMovie.Models.Movie'. Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database servers is not supported. Instead, create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used"

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410673/using-the-same-dbcompiledmodel-to-create-contexts-against-different-types-of-dat).

It seems there's an issue in controller creation when using SQL CE