# How to connect to Oracle 11g in MVC3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

I am having a problem to connect to oracle 11g and I have worked upon it for almost a day now. I am using C# and coding in an Mvc3 way.
I have the following connection string in web.config file

```
<add name = "VIPSoracleContext"
    connectionString = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE; User Id=SYS; Password=PSWRD;"
    providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

I even tried the following connection string again

```
<add name = "VIPSoracleContext"
    connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=’wkkdmtk’)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME’vipstest’)));User Id=’myID’;Password=’PSWRD’;"
    providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
```

I still have the following error when creating a controller with read/write templates

error:
    Unable to retrieve metadata for '...Models.person'.
    A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection'. The store provider might not be functioning correctly.

How can I successfuly connect to oracle 11g with code first? Can anyone please help.
Thanx in advnce!

Comment: Your second connection string looks wrong, especially the service_name part. And the quotes don't look like ordinary quotes (and they are not necessary in the connection string). [Also don't connect as SYS, and don't post your SYS password :-) ]

Comment: Thanx Mat. But is there anything wrong with the first connectionstring? What do you sugest me to do coz you just mentioned that the string "looks" wrong?

Comment: Correct it :-)  I don't know the technology you're using at all, so can't help you there. The second version is wrong, as I detailed above. (And [edit] your post to remove your password.)

Comment: Is this entity framework?  MVC isn't a database access technology...

Comment: Yes Jace, ASP.NET MVC3 is one of the methods of developing ASP.NET applications. I have connected to different DBs but Im having problms when connecting to oracle DB. This is entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

**I got it atlast guys!**

Followed this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68tlel4iJdM
But be aware of the default constractor of the context class because if you don't controll it, you will get an error.
Follow this link to check what to take cure of with the default constractor:
[Add Controller in MVC4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172074/add-controller-in-mvc4-not-working)
especially the answer by **Arnaldo237**.

You will need **ODP.net** so that provider name **Oracle.DataAccess.Client** can work.

Enjoy your code at Home.... **happy....**