# Adding Controller in Web.Config for MVC4 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4

My project is a Web project for MVC4 and I am trying to add a controller after adding a connection string to the web.config folder, but every time i try to add it, i get the following message:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for TestFFL14.Models.LivePlayers. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is the LivePlayers Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestFFL14.Models
{
    public class LivePlayers
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Nid { get; set; }
        public string Plyr { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public class LivePlayersDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LivePlayers> Players { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this connection string but not having any success:

```
<add name="LivePlayersDBContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=testdb;User Id=pkioko;Password=stunner1" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are adding connection string in root web.config file not in web.config in 'Views' folder

Comment: It is in the root web.config

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172074/add-controller-in-mvc4-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add below LivePlayersDBContext  constructor with connectionstring name as parameter to base constructor

```
public class LivePlayersDBContext : DbContext
    {
       public LivePlayersDBContext ():base("LivePlayersDBContext")
          {
          }     
        public DbSet<LivePlayers> Players { get; set; }
    }
```